# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) on Xubuntu [Not Solved]

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dpkg, sudo

I'm really tired of getting this error;

```
Xubuntu E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried sudo apt-get -f install, apt install -f and  sudo apt --fix-broken install
AND THEY DIDN'T WORK. I'M DRIVING CRAZY BECAUSE OF THIS ERROR AND THIS ERROR IS NOT THE ONLY ERROR.

```
dpkg: warning:the file listing the files of the package 'libwayland-client0: i386' could not be found; it is assumed that the package does not already have any files
```

That's all i need a solution to this problem.

Comment: At first try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwayland-client0:i386` .

Comment: Also, if that doesn’t work, `sudo apt update && sudo apt clean` before trying your install command.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwayland-client0:i386` and `sudo apt update && sudo apt clean` didn't work. 'libwayland-client0: i386' wasn't the only broken package.There is a lot more broken package like that.

Comment: `E: The Release file does not exist in the 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release' store.N: Such a repository cannot be safely updated, so the repository is disabled.N: For detailed information about depot creation and user configuration, it can be found on the apt-secure(8) guide page.E: There is no Release file in the 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu release' store.N: Such a repository cannot be safely updated, so the repository is disabled.N: For detailed information about depot creation and user configuration, see the apt-secure(8) guide page`

Comment: thats what i get after sudo apt update && sudo apt clean.

Comment: Deactivate both ppa's that are mentioned in your last comment. Both have no packages for your distro release.

Comment: @nobody how can i deactive?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed  I would prefer ppa-purge.

Comment: Thanks but it says;

```tokmaq@root:~$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:/ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release
Unable to handle repository shortcut 'ppa:/ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release'```

Comment: IM STUCK ON THIS FRICKING OS AND I CANT GET OUT. I TRIED EVERYTHING DUDE. E V E R Y T H I N G. IM DRIVING CRAZY

Comment: Oh come on first think then type. You added this ppa's not ubuntu. `sudo apt install ppa-purge` (i hope it is working). `sudo ppa-purge ppa:gezakovacs/ppa` and `sudo ppa-purge ppa:wireshark-dev/stable`

Comment: @nobody while i'm installing ppa purge i got unmet dependencies error.I tried to fix them on Synaptic but didn't work again.Now all i want is how can i install a operating system without any usb or dvd (except unetbootin because of the broken packages it didn't work on my pc)

Comment: Make a backup from your data! and add `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to your question you can edit it.

Comment: I don't need a backup.and what is this? ```tokmaq@root:~$ ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Ağu 12 13:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Ağu  5 17:35 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  148 Ağu 12 13:30 nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-hirsute.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  148 Ağu 12 13:30 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-hirsute.list```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-hirsute.list
```

[restore default repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Then run

```
sudo apt update
```

when apt is not complaining then try to run

sudo dpkg --configure -a

NO error so far?

```
sudo apt -f install && sudo sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Oh need no backup? So you have no important datas :(